# A function in my program seems like it should work but occasionally gives the wrong output

Tags: c#, function, winforms

I wrote a function that checks for a given cell in a grid if it is a legal move following the rules of the board-game called Reversi otherwise known as Othello. The rules are that a circle can only be placed on the grid whenever the newly placed circle and a previous placed circle bounds one of the opponents circles. The majority of the time the function gives the right output (i.e. true when it is a legal move and false when it is a legal move), but some moves that are legal by the previously stated rules are not deemed as a legal move by the function.

I've tried to use the console to check at every step at which cell the function is currently looking and what the value of the cell is to determine what goes wrong. This has only led me to being even more confused.

The following code is the doomed-function:

```
bool legalMove(int row, int col)
    {
        // Check if the cell is occupied
        if (board[row,col] != 0)
            return false;

        // Check if there's an opponents circle somewhere around it
        for (int i = -1; i<=1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j<=1; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    continue;

                int currentRow = row + i;
                int currentCol = col + j;

                if (currentRow >= 0 && currentRow < board.GetLength(0) && currentCol >= 0 && currentCol < board.GetLength(1) && board[currentRow,currentCol] == -turn)
                {
                    // Now we know that there's an opponents circle somewhere around this space, we now check if it can be captured
                    while(true)
                    {
                        currentRow += i;
                        currentCol += j;

                        Console.WriteLine($"currentRow: {currentRow}, currentCol: {currentCol}, value: {board[currentRow,currentCol]}");

                        if (currentRow < 0 || currentRow >= board.GetLength(0) || currentCol < 0 || currentCol >= board.GetLength(1) || board[currentRow, currentCol] == 0)
                            return false; // Outside of the board or an empty space
                        else if (board[currentRow,currentCol] == turn)
                            return true; // No empty spaces between our cell and another cell of ours 
                    }
                }
            }
        return false; // No cell found around ours
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The entire program is the following (hope it can help):

```
/* TO-DO
* Make function out of no legal move and tidy up
* Calculate amount of circles of player to determine the winner
* Make victory label better
!!!Tidy up flipCircles method and fix legalMove method
Create a slider and make it change the gridSize
Make GUI change empty space when board gets smaller or bigger
Tidy up the 2x calling to check what the score is
*/



// Library imports
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Game class
class Game : Form
{
    // Declare variables
    private Board board;
    private Button newGame, help;
    private Font font;
    private Label countRed, countBlue, gameState;
    private TrackBar sizeBoard;

    public int gridSize = 6;

    public Game()
    {
        // Set the form properties
        ClientSize = new Size(520, 670); Text = "Reversi";

        // Creating the GUI and adding it to the form
        newGame = new Button(); Controls.Add(newGame);
        help = new Button(); Controls.Add(help);

        font = new Font("Arial", 14);
        countBlue = new Label(); Controls.Add(countBlue); countBlue.Font = font;
        countRed = new Label(); Controls.Add(countRed); countRed.Font = font;
        gameState = new Label(); Controls.Add(gameState); gameState.Font = font;

        board = new Board(gridSize); Controls.Add(board);

        // Settings of the GUI
        newGame.Size = new Size(100, 30); newGame.Location = new Point(150, 10); newGame.Text = "New Game"; newGame.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        help.Size = new Size(100, 30); help.Location = new Point(270, 10); help.Text = "Help"; help.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        countBlue.Size = new Size(110, 30); countBlue.Location = new Point(150, 50); countBlue.Text = $"{board.countBlue} stones"; countBlue.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
        countRed.Size = new Size(110, 30); countRed.Location = new Point(150, 90); countRed.Text = $"{board.countRed} stones"; countRed.ForeColor = Color.Firebrick;
        gameState.Size = new Size(150, 30); gameState.Location = new Point(270, 90); gameState.Text = $"{board.playersTurn}";

        // Events //



        // Label events
        newGame.Click += reset;
        help.Click += calculateHelp;

        // Board events
        board.MouseClick += clicked;

        //Paint event
        Paint += paint;
    }

    // Event-handlers //

    // Label event-handlers
    private void reset(object e, EventArgs ea)
    {
        board.Reset();
        countBlue.Text = $"{board.countBlue} stones";
        countRed.Text = $"{board.countRed} stones";
        gameState.Text = $"{board.playersTurn}";
    }

    private void calculateHelp(object e, EventArgs ea)
    {
        board.SetHelp();
    }

    // Board event-handlers
    private void clicked(object e, MouseEventArgs mea)
    {
        board.Clicked(mea.Location);
        countBlue.Text = $"{board.countBlue} stones";
        countRed.Text = $"{board.countRed} stones";
        gameState.Text = $"{board.playersTurn}";

        // Now check if there's a legalMove if not
        //if (timesNoLegalMove > 1)
        gameState.Text = $"{board.playersTurn}";
    }

    // Paint event-handler
    private void paint(object e, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {
        Graphics gr = pea.Graphics;

        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, 100, 45, 31, 31);
        gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Firebrick, 100, 85, 31, 31);
    }
}

// Board class
class Board : Label
{
    // Declare all global variables used in this class
    private int[,] board;
    private int size;
    private int turn = 1; // 1 is blue, -1 is red
    private bool legalMoveExists = true;
    public int timesNoLegalMove = 0;
    private bool help = false;

    // Create the board and set settings + events
    public Board(int gridSize)
    {
        size = gridSize;

        Size = new Size(size * 50, size * 50);
        Location = new Point(10 + (25 * (10 - size)), 120 + (25 * (10 - size)));
        BackColor = Color.White;
        board = new int[size, size];

        startingState();

        Paint += Draw;
    }

    // Sets the values of the center 4 squares to that of the starting circles
    private void startingState()
    {
        board[(size / 2)-1, (size / 2)-1] = 1;
        board[(size / 2), (size / 2)] = 1;
        board[(size / 2), (size / 2) - 1] = -1;
        board[(size / 2) - 1, (size / 2)] = -1;
    }

    // Resets the board when New Game is clicked
    public void Reset()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
                board[row, col] = 0;
        startingState();
        turn = 1;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void SetHelp()
    {
        if (help)
            help = false;
        else
            help = true;
        Invalidate();
    }

    public string playersTurn
    {
        get
        {
            if (turn == 1)
                return "It's Blue's turn";
            if (turn == -1)
                return "It's Red's turn";
            else
            {
                if (countBlue > countRed)
                    return "Blue has won the game!";
                if (countRed > countBlue)
                    return "Red has won the game!";
                else
                    return "It's a draw!";
            }
        }

    }

    public int countRed
    {
        get
        {
            return board.Cast<int>().Count(n => n == -1);
        }
    }

    public int countBlue
    {
        get
        {
            return board.Cast<int>().Count(n => n == 1);
        }
    }

    bool legalMove(int row, int col)
    {
        // Check if the cell is occupied
        if (board[row,col] != 0)
            return false;

        // Check if there's an opponents circle somewhere around it
        for (int i = -1; i<=1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j<=1; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    continue;

                int currentRow = row + i;
                int currentCol = col + j;

                if (currentRow >= 0 && currentRow < board.GetLength(0) && currentCol >= 0 && currentCol < board.GetLength(1) && board[currentRow,currentCol] == -turn)
                {
                    // Now we know that there's an opponents circle somewhere around this space, we now check if it can be captured
                    while(true)
                    {
                        currentRow += i;
                        currentCol += j;

                        if (currentRow < 0 || currentRow >= board.GetLength(0) || currentCol < 0 || currentCol >= board.GetLength(1) || board[currentRow, currentCol] == 0)
                            return false; // Outside of the board or an empty space
                        else if (board[currentRow,currentCol] == turn)
                            return true; // No empty spaces between our cell and another cell of ours 
                    }
                }
            }
        return false; // No cell found around ours
    }

    private void flipCircles(int row, int col)
    {
        // Check all eight directions from the current position
        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)
        {
            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++)
            {
                // Skip the current position
                if (r == row && c == col)
                    continue;

                int rr = r;
                int cc = c;

                // Check if the next position in this direction is a valid position on the board
                // and if it is occupied by the opponent's piece
                if (rr >= 0 && rr < board.GetLength(0) && cc >= 0 && cc < board.GetLength(1) && board[rr, cc] == -turn)
                {
                    // Keep moving in this direction until we find the current player's piece or an empty cell
                    while (true)
                    {
                        rr += r - row;
                        cc += c - col;

                        // If we have reached an invalid position or an empty cell, break out of the loop
                        if (rr < 0 || rr >= board.GetLength(0) || cc < 0 || cc >= board.GetLength(1) || board[rr, cc] == 0)
                            break;

                        // If we have found the current player's piece, flip all the pieces between the current position and the player's piece
                        if (board[rr, cc] == turn)
                        {
                            while (rr != r || cc != c)
                            {
                                rr -= r - row;
                                cc -= c - col;
                                board[rr, cc] = turn;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    // Sets the value of a clicked cell to either 1 (Blue), or -1 (Red)
    public void Clicked(Point mea)
    {
        int rowClicked = mea.X / 50;
        int colClicked = mea.Y /50;

        if (legalMove(rowClicked, colClicked))
        {
            board[rowClicked, colClicked] = turn;
            flipCircles(rowClicked, colClicked);
            help = false;
            turn = -turn;
            legalMoveExists = false;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    // Draws the entire board and all circles
    void Draw(object e, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {
        Graphics gr = pea.Graphics;
        legalMoveExists = false;

        for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0); row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < board.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                // Draw the background tiles
                if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0 || row % 2 != 0 && col % 2 != 0)
                    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, 50 * row, 50 * col, 50, 50);
                // Draw circles
                if (board[row, col] == 1) // Blue circles
                    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, 50 * row - 1, 50 * col - 1, 51, 51);
                else if (board[row, col] == -1) // Red circles
                    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Firebrick, 50 * row - 1, 50 * col - 1, 51, 51);
                // Check for legal moves and draw help circles if the help button has been pressed
                else if (legalMove(row, col))
                {
                    legalMoveExists = true;
                    timesNoLegalMove = 0;
                    if (help) // Help circles
                        gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 50 * row + 9, 50 * col + 9, 31, 31);
                }
            }

        //  Make this a function
        if (!legalMoveExists)
        {
            turn = -turn;
            timesNoLegalMove++;
            Invalidate();
            if (timesNoLegalMove > 1)
                turn = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Main run
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Game());
    }
}
```

Comment: impossible to debug without seeing the whole program

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I've added all of the code, hope it can give more context.

Comment: **[Using the  built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** is easier than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that the function you wrote to scan the surrounding cells is failing sporadically and that it's difficult to diagnose. It was easy to reproduce the failures by running your code, but I wasn't able to see an obvious way to effectively debug it.

It "might" be more effective to *improve the algorithm* where it's more methodical in how it inspects the surrounding cells in the first place, which would also be easier to debug if necessary. One solid way to do this would be to use custom [Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods) where you could use a standard `foreach` pattern to inspect virtual "lines" radiating in the eight directions. At each 'yield' you can check to see whether a determination can be made in terms of either a "legal move" or a "capture".

---

Here's a proof-of-concept grid that is intended to demonstrate how the iterators work. It *doesn't* evaluate the cells in terms of game play in any way but you can see how it would lend itself to doing that. The idea here is to click any cell and observe the markup of U-R-D-L. It may also help to see it working so you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reversi-iterators-01.git) this sample and set breakpoints.

[image: iterating from points]

---

Left, Right, Up, Down iterator examples are shown - diagonals would follow the same pattern. The mouse down control passes the starting cell coordinate position as a Point:

```
public IEnumerable<Point> CellsUp(Point point)
{
    while (true)
    {
        point = new Point(point.X, point.Y - 1);
        if (point.Y < 0) break;
        yield return point;
    }
}
public IEnumerable<Point> CellsRight(Point point, int max)
{
    while (true)
    {
        point = new Point(point.X + 1, point.Y);
        if (point.X == max) break;
        yield return point;
    }
}
public IEnumerable<Point> CellsDown(Point point, int max)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return point;
        point = new Point(point.X, point.Y + 1);
        if (point.Y == max) break;
    }
}
public IEnumerable<Point> CellsLeft(Point point)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return point;
        point = new Point(point.X - 1, point.Y);
        if (point.X < 0) break;
    }
}
```

---

The code lays the groundwork for a methodical scan outward from any given point.

```
private void legalMoveIterationStub(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clear();
    if(sender is Control control)
    {
        control.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        control.Refresh();
        var pos = board.GetCellPosition(control);
        var pt = new Point(pos.Column, pos.Row);
        Control ctrl;
        foreach (var point in CellsUp(pt))
        {
            ctrl = board.GetControlFromPosition(point.X, point.Y);
            ctrl.Text = "U";
            ctrl.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(DEMO_DELAY_MS);
            // This is where the cell inspects e.g. for "empty square"
            // or color. Chances are, some condition will be met
            // and you will break from here rather than iterate
            // all the way to the edge of the board each time.
        }
        foreach (var point in CellsRight(pt, board.ColumnCount))
        {
            ctrl = board.GetControlFromPosition(point.X, point.Y);
            ctrl.Text = "R";
            ctrl.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(DEMO_DELAY_MS);
        }
        foreach (var point in CellsDown(pt, board.ColumnCount))
        {
            ctrl = board.GetControlFromPosition(point.X, point.Y);
            ctrl.Text = "D";
            ctrl.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(DEMO_DELAY_MS);
        }
        foreach (var point in CellsLeft(pt))
        {
            ctrl = board.GetControlFromPosition(point.X, point.Y);
            ctrl.Text = "L";
            ctrl.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(DEMO_DELAY_MS);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The demo board has been mocked like this for testing purposes:

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int col = 0; col < board.ColumnCount; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < board.RowCount; row++)
            {
                var tile = new Label
                {
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                    Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
                    Margin = new Padding(1),
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                };
                board.Controls.Add(tile, col, row);
                tile.MouseDown += legalMove;
            }
        }
    }
    void clear()
    {
        foreach (Control control in board.Controls)
        {
            control.Text = string.Empty;
            control.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }
        board.Refresh();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```